# Combinatorics Selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, combinations

There are N distinct boxes of balls in total. There are P boxes each containing A number of balls and remaining Q boxes contains B number of balls each.

Given a number X, what are the total the number of ways in which you can pick at least X balls from the boxes.

P+Q = N

Example: `Number of P boxes=2` which contain 2 balls each, `Number of Q boxes=1` which contain 2 balls. `X=3(Given)` where `x=minimum number of balls to be picked`
So, P+Q=3 (total number of boxes)
Combinations for the number of ways to pick atleast x i.e. 3 balls would be:

> combinations of 3:(111),(210),(120),(021),(012),(201),(102)
>   combinations of 4:(220)(202)(022)(211)(121)(112)
>   combinations of 5:(212)(122)(221)
>   combinations of 6: (222)
>   total Combinations: 17

My Approach:
I have used "Stars and Bars Approach":

> To calculate combinations of 6: x+y+z=6 which is converted into (2-x)+(2-y)+(2-z)=6 giving out x+y+z=0.
>   So, the combination of 6 becomes Binomial(2C2)=1
>   Similarly, Combinations of 5 becomes Binomial(3C2)=3
>   Combinations of 4= Binomial(4C2)=6
>  
>   Combinations of 3= Binomial(5C2)=10

```
1+3+6+10=20
but the answer should be 1+3+6+7=17
```

Edge case has appeared on calculating the combinations of 3. How should I tackle this problem?

```
global total_combinations
total_combinations=0

from math import factorial

def combinations(a):
    global total_combinations
    bars=numberofAs+numberofBs-1
    stars=a
    total_combinations+=factorial(stars+bars)/(factorial(bars)*factorial(stars))


numberofAs,numberofBs,numberofballsinA,numberofballsinB=map(int,raw_input().split())

x=int(raw_input())

operational_array=[]

for i in range(numberofAs):
    operational_array.append(numberofballsinA)

for i in range(numberofBs):
    operational_array.append(numberofballsinB)

max_x=sum(operational_array) #calculate combinations from x to max_x
k=max_x

for i in range(max_x,x-1,-1):
    k=max_x-i
    combinations(k)

print total_combinations
```

PS:I found this question online but it seems interesting to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you take some time to debug your problem by stepping through it one line at a time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ have some great tips to get you started.

Comment: Do they all have the same amount of balls in each box?

Comment: @Miket25 P boxes will contain same number of balls and Q boxes will contain same number of balls but it is not necessary that balls in p are equal to q.

Comment: @Miket25 There can be  P boxes each having 3 balls and Q boxes each having 7 balls .Also there can boxes each having 7 balls and Q boxes also having 7 balls.So balls in P and Q need not be same but balls in P each will be equal and same goes for Q.

Comment: @Miket25 can the error be eliminated using inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: It sounds more of using a mix of bionomials and multinoimals

Comment: @Miket25 do you have a solution?

Comment: I don't. If your original question is seeking for a mathematical answer, I suggest your best option is asking on math stack exchange.

Comment: This doesn't look like python-3.x

Comment: The print and raw_input show it to be python 2. The fact that you have your own "combinations" instead of using itertools is a huge red flag. You may be reinventing the wheel.